# Semantic-ui-react Tab panes activeIndex change breaks component's defaultValue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Semantic UI React Dropdown or Select components can take a defaultValue property, which I set to what I have in state, for ex:

```
<Dropdown
    defaultValue={this.state.changes.campaignAgent || null}
```

The thing is, it works! So, if a user selects a different part of the vertical fluid tab Menu, it will render the tab render content on the right.

The problem is, that sometimes it renders so fast that the value in state that it utilizes when switching activeIndex between panes it ends up being empty. The confusing part about this is that the state is correct and essentially what the user selected in the form is accurately in state, but it's a visual bug due to some sort of rendering race condition within semantic ui react. Not sure if there's something I can do to force the pane to delay, keep in mind these tab panes are for a form.

I've tried adding further specific conditional logic on panes, but the form is too dynamic. I've got defaultValue props on form fields and selects set to the state so they should show, not sure why they disappear.

I expect that when you switch between active Tab panes, that the render JSX shouldn't render so fast that the defaultValue set to state values persistent in react component state is ignored leaving an almost empty visual looking drop down when going back to that tab after selecting it.